# How to use auto completion in Python console applications?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, autocomplete

I have a Python console program, which uses `input()` from `builtin` to read data from the user. The program has a configuration option, which requires the user to input several paths. I would like to ease these inputs e.g. by a tab-completion.

[image]

Is it possible to implement an auto completion e.g. for path names? I see currently no way to hook into the `input` function to catch `tab` events/key presses...

Does the Python standard library provide such a feature?

The solution must work on Windows, Linux and Mac OS :).

**Please note: I'm not looking for auto completion in Pythons interactive shell/console.**

Answer (score 1):

CLI Autocompletion is not included in Python standard library.

You can try:

- urwid (http://urwid.org/tutorial/index.html) for a rather low level CLI library
- Cement for a full CLI framework (http://cement.readthedocs.io and http://cement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/bash_auto_completion/)

In all cases it's probably quite a bit of work :-/